# Index products with cron

Tags: php, magento, cron

I need to re-index all products in Magento every night.

I know this can be achieved with:
php /home/path/to/magento/shell/indexer.php reindexall

But how do I add this call into the built-in cron mechanism in Magento?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Step 1 : Set cron to be executed every 5 minutes or a higher frequency.
2. In crontab node :

       
           
               
                   0 2 * * *
               
               
                   catalog/product_indexer_price::reindexAll

you change 2 in cron_expr as per your day value.

Comment: its in xml file.If you do have complete code set just search for crontab in xml files.